# The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction

Tags: c#, transactions, repository, entity-framework-6, unit-of-work

I am getting error as :

An error was reported while committing a database transaction but it could not be determined whether the transaction succeeded or failed on the database server. See the inner exception and http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313468 for more information.

The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction.

i am trying to insert data to DB using Entity Frameowrk using MapStoredProcedure approach.

My Code :

```
this.MapToStoredProcedures(e => e.Insert(v => v.HasName("uspInsertUser").Result(rs => rs.UserId, "UserId")));

 public ActionResult Add(User userDetails)
        {
            try
            {
                _unitOfWorkAsync.BeginTransaction();

                _userService.Insert(userDetails);
                _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();

                _unitOfWorkAsync.Commit(); // This line gives error
                ModelState.Clear();    

                return View("Add");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _unitOfWorkAsync.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }
```

The most weird thing about this is if i keep a breakpoint and debug the code while insert it insert successfully.

However, when i insert without any breakpoint enabled it gives me above error.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `await SaveChangesAsync();` and make your `Add` method async

Comment: how to make Add method async ?

Comment: Change it's signature to `public async Task<ActionResult> Add(User userDetails)` or better `public async Task<ActionResult> AddAsync(User userDetails)`. Read something about async controllers in ASP MVC. If you don't want to make it async: change `_unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();` to `_unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync().Wait();`

Comment: I have added public async Task<ActionResult> Add(User userDetails)
        {  await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync().Wait();} it gives comiple error : Cannot await void

Comment: Adding `.Wait()` makes it synchronous again. You need to do `await SaveChangesAsync();` Do you want me to type this up in an answer that explains it a bit better?

Comment: If i remove .Wait i am geeting this error "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75092/discussion-between-alex-and-user662285).